# Create disk image of runing virtual Windows 2019 then import and run it on another VMware Workstation

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, disk-image, vmdk, macrium

I am trying to create disk image of runing virtual Windows 2019. I don't have access to actual VMware Workstation. I only have a remote access to Windows. After exporting the image I need to import and run it on another VMware Workstation. Is it viable? I would appreciate if you can give me few tips. Can I create image using Macrium Reflect or would I need to create a VHD image?

Answer (score 2):

You can actualy do a P2V of the Windows 2019 machine and then import it to Workstation. Disk2VHD or StarWind V2V converter tools which may help. StarWind can P2V directly to VMDK needed for Workstation.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/v2v-help/PhysicalDisksandP2VScenario.html